# Why doesn't this argument of the LinearGradient constructor seem to work?

Tags: android, android-drawable, linear-gradients, android-shapedrawable

I want to set a custom drawable with a linear gradient as the background drawable of the bar in my `SeekBar`. I am creating the LinearGradient in the second statement in the following snippet, and doing it like so:

```
// Creating the drawable:
ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
Shader linearGradientShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 300, 20, new int[] { Color.RED, Color.BLUE },
new float[] { 0, 1 }, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(linearGradientShader);
shapeDrawable.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 30);

seekBar.setProgressDrawable(shapeDrawable);
```

The problem here is that, according to the [**specification**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html), the 6th parameter is defined as

> May be null. The relative positions [0..1] of each corresponding color in the colors array. If this is null, the the colors are distributed evenly along the gradient line.

I wanted both the red and blue colors to be distributed evenly, i.e. half the shape should appear redish and half should appear bluish (like the following image).

[image]

**So I tried `null`, `new float[] {0, 0.5f}`, and `new float[] {0, 1}` as values of the 6th argument. I got the following three results respectively.**

1. For `null`: [image]
2. For `new float[] {0, 0.5f}`: [image]
3. For `new float[] {0, 1}`: [image]

**Show where am I going wrong? How should I fix this?**

Comment: see `ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory`

Comment: @pskink Thank you I am gonna implement it.

Comment: @pskink Thank you so very much. This works. Can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: note that when using `ShaderFactory` you dont need to call `shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(linearGradientShader);` and `shapeDrawable.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 30);`

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't do that. Thank you so very much.

Comment: your welcome, no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

> ShapeDrawable#setShaderFactory(ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory factory)

the factory has a method `Shader resize(int width, int height)` which is called every time your drawable bounds change and this is a place where you should return your `LinearGradient` shader based on `width` / `height` parameters

as you will see you can now just pass null `positions` and colors will be distributed evenly